# How to handle multilevel includes in C?

Tags: c, gcc, include, c-preprocessor, multi-level

I have second level include that is giving me grief:

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
function2                      /var/tmp//ccAPaWbT.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to run
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Main file:

```
#include "functions02.c"
int main(){
int x = funcion2();
}
```

functions02.c file:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS02_C
#define FUNCTIONS02_C
int funcion2();
#if __INCLUDE_LEVEL__ == 0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "functions01.c"
int main() {
   return function2();
}
#endif
int function2()
   return function1();
}
#endif
```

functions01.c file:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS01_C
#define FUNCTIONS01_C
int funcion1();
#if __INCLUDE_LEVEL__ == 0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main() {
   return function1();
}
#endif
int function1()
   return 10;
}
#endif
```

I am assuming that this can be fixed manipulated using `__INCLUDE_LEVEL__` or manipulating linking on `gcc` compiling but I can't find forking variant.

First of all is it possible to achieve what I am looking for without putting functions in external header files?
Second what would be the correct way of doing it?

*EDIT:*
I realized that I had forgotten to add function dependencies to them. That is the includes which are used by functions can  not be excluded by adding them just next to main function warped in exclusion if close.

Comment: Ouch.  What are you trying to achieve here?  I can't imagine many situations in which I would like to have conditional compilation in my C files (as opposed to in headers).

Comment: Including `.c` files is pretty non-idiomatic.  +1 to @Gian - what are you trying to do here?

Comment: This is a linker error, not compile, right?  That has nothing to do with includes.

Comment: I have a very strict file naming conditions on one particular system and I can't have header files or even split c files in to two different files one holding functions other just execution calls. Thou thanks for the warnings I would never do something like that if I would have a choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to include / exclude any part of the code using compile time flags (and in the code using #if's) as you are trying to do.

In  your case, I assume you have not defined `__INCLUDE_LEVEL__` flag, hence the linker is not able to find funciton2, so the error.

If you define it, you will have three "main()" :-), it will fail again. So, you need to rework your code a bit.

Also, #include'ing a "C" file is not advisable and not used in practice. I assume you are just trying to experiment & learn, which is fine.